# Replacing Part of a string within a group Concat

Tags: mysql, case, concat, replace

I have part of a string that I would like to remove when selecting.  The Problem is that there are a few pieces within the string that changes.  This is what I have so far.

```
 Select
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Substr(Concat(Round(ms_cart.cart_qty), 'x', ms_cart.cart_sku), 1, 12), Concat(' | ', ms_cart_options.co_opt_name), Replace(ms_cart_options.co_opt_name, '<h3>This is a buddy package.  Who will the buddy photo be taken with</h3>: THIS PART CHANGES <H3> What team?: THIS PART CHANGES', ''))
as Items FROM ms_cart
  INNER JOIN ms_orders ON ms_orders.order_id = ms_cart.cart_order
 INNER JOIN ms_cart_options ON ms_cart_options.co_cart_id=ms_cart.cart_id
```

Comment: ```GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN value = 'value to be skipped' THEN NULL ELSE value END)```

Comment: Thank you, will this work if the 'value to be skipped' isn't the entire value but just a portion of the value?  ex The string is '<h3>This is a buddy package.  Who will the buddy photo be taken with?</h3>: Customers Answer'  But I only want to skip '<h3>This is a buddy package.  Who will the buddy photo be taken with?</h3>: '

Comment: *will this work if the 'value to be skipped' isn't the entire value but just a portion of the value?* No, of course. In such case use simple `.. GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(value, 'value to be skipped')) ..`.

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions, but what would the best way to define the variable in the value?  Ex.  The "Customers Answer" that always changes:  '<h3>This is a buddy package. Who will the buddy photo be taken with?</h3>: Customers Answer'